# Make a link/button 100% clickable

Tags: html, button, mailchimp

Hoping someone can help. I've created a button in mailchimp with the below code, to allow me to use a button within a text box. It's looking great, my only issue is that the text in button is clickable but I want the whole button to be clickable. I've added `'display: inline-block'` as advised on here but doesn't seem to have an impact

Can anyone offer any advice?

Thanks

```
<center>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#F287B7;" width="60%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: -0.5px; line-height: 150%; padding: 15px 30px; width: 100%; text-align: center;"><a href="https://www.littlebird.co.uk/membership/join?utm_source=toucan&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=toucan15" style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank; display: inline-block">Learn More</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery to do. Just give to your `<td>` element an id or class.
Then with jQuery create an event "click".

```
<script>
    $(() => {
        $("#clickable").on("click", function () {
            window.open("https://www.littlebird.co.uk/membership/join?utm_source=toucan&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=toucan15");
        });
    });
</script>
<center>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#F287B7;" width="60%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="clickable"
                    style="cursor: pointer; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: -0.5px; line-height: 150%; padding: 15px 30px; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                    <a href="https://www.littlebird.co.uk/membership/join?utm_source=toucan&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=toucan15"
                        style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank; display: inline-block">Learn
                        More</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</center>
```

You should import jQuery library.
Look that I have added `style="cursor: pointer;`in `td` to change the cursor.